Function addgeometrycolumn does not exist in QGIS Model designer
I'm using Export to PostgreSQL algorythm in QGIS Model Designer to load my layer into PostGIS database. You can see the parameters on the screenshot.
I manage to connect to the database after I run the model, but then in the log window it says:
function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','points','geom',32640,'POI...

PostGIS v3.4 is installed. How to fix this?
UPD. I managed to fix the error. Although I had to enable PostGIS with a query in model designer (CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;). The addgeometrycolumn error no longer appears, but the layer is not exported into the database anyway. And also enabling the PostGIS extension runs AFTER the export operation (PostgreSQL execute SQL algorithm), which is not logical. This time I did it manually but I need to enable it BEFORE any further operations, how to do it? because this enabling query is not linked to any other operation or output, it's just in the 'air' disconnected from anything

@Bera yes I have. Although I had to do it with a query in model designer (CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS  postgis;). The addgeometrycolumn error no longer appears, but the layer is not exported into the database anyway. And also the export operation (PostgreSQL execute SQL algorithm) runs before the enabling the PostGIS extension, this time I did it manually but I need to enable it BEFORE any further operations, how to do it? because this enabling query is not linked to any other operation or output, it's just in the 'air' disconnected from anything

The gis PostGIS connection have permission to create tables in the database and schema?
